# Is it possible to capture the overlay name instead just the signature in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin `signaturepadView` on capturing Signature. Also, saving the signature works fine. I also want to capture the text and stuff.

This is what I want to capture
[image]

Instead I got this
[image]

Comment: You can capture a screenshot of an entire View.  There are numerous existing questions on how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Xamarin.Essentials: Screenshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/screenshot) to capture the whole view of the `Signature`. Here's the sample code below for your reference:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EcentArgs e){

     if(Screenshot.IsCaptureSupported){

           var screenshot = await Screenshot.CaptureAsync();
           var stream = await screenshot.OpenReadAsync();

           ImageScreenshot.Source  = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
    }
}
```